# Matlab multiple matrices with a condition

Tags: matlab, matrix

I know I can pass all the element of the matrix and do that.

but maybe there is another option.

I want to do:

```
mat1 = mat2 * mat1;
```

each element in mat1 that become to negative or bigger than 255, I want to leave the previous element.

for example (the result is not true, this is only for the example):

```
mat1 = [10  25  12
        33  7   163
        232 13  77]

mat2 = [-1  2  -3
         4 -5   6
         -7 -8  9]
```

asume mat1 = mat2 * mat1 gives:

```
mat1 = [-77.32  59    298
        0       -33   12
        -600     256   80]
```

so I want to repair mat1 to be:

```
mat1 = [10   59  12
        0    7   12
        232  13  80]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you have a matrix multiplication

```
mat2 * mat1
```

Best is to store the matrix multiplication result in a third matrix

```
mat3 = mat2 * mat1
```

With

```
idx = (mat3 < 0 | mat3 > 255)
```

you a matrix with ones where you want to replace and zero where not. Apply this index to replace the values in mat3 with the values of mat1

```
mat3(idx) = mat1(idx)
```

The result is a matrix in which every element smaller than 0 or bigger than 255 has been replaced with the value of mat1.

Answer (score 2):

I think that multiplying the matrices and then "fixing" the result is the best option. Here is why:

1. You have calculate each cell in the product matrix to know if you want to keep it or not
2. Matlab preforms matrix multiplications really fast

So I would simply go for:

```
prod = mat1 * mat2
mask = (prod < 0) | (prod > 255)
prod(mask) = mat1(mask)
```

Comment: I believe this is wrong. mask is all zeros after you execute line 2. You need a `|`, not a multiplication.